# Did fraudsters access my SMS verification code?

Tags: phone, scam

A very strange sequence of events resulted in some unknown person gaining access to my online banking (with CIBC). I've since recovered my account, but I am very eager to understand what happened:

- I live in Toronto, Canada. I and many people around me regularly receive spam phonecalls (e.g. "The IRS" claiming I am wanted for tax fraud, eventually leading to a request for credit card info). These calls originate from numbers that share the same first 3 digits (after area code) as our own numbers. Say my Toronto phone number is 1-647-123-4567; the spam calls I receive will come from 1-647-123-XXXX.
- I have always picked up these calls as I enjoy (don't judge me) talking to these fraudsters, saying weird things to them, and wasting their time.
- I received a call from a phone number matching my own 3 digits, and picked up. The guy on the other end asked if he could speak to some girl. I told him I didn't know who he was talking about. He proceeded to vent frustration, saying that this girl had given him my number, and told him he could take her out to a movie, etc. I expressed genuine sympathy, saying I felt bad for him. There was nothing explicitly fraudulent about the call, *but*...
- Upon exiting the call I had two texts from CIBC. The first was from one minute earlier (exactly when I got the call), saying *"This is your CIBC verification code: 123456. Enter it within 10 minutes"*. The second was from 20 seconds later, saying: *"You've successfully changed your CIBC password. If this wasn't you, call <cibc fraud department #>"*

This was, of course, nerve-wracking. My CIBC account really was compromised - my password had changed and I couldn't log in. I received emails saying that the phone number associated with my account had successfully changed, and that my bank account had successfully been linked to ApplePay.

Since this incident I have regained access to my online banking and undone all fraudulent changes. I've been issued a new credit card. I've established a secret phrase with CIBC. I've called equifax and transunion to ensure they apply additional verification steps when any changes are requested on my account. I've also upgraded all my passwords. My whole life I've been conscientious with my credit card, never having lost it or any piece of technology which may have had credentials saved on it. I've certainly never divulged anything sensitive to a scam-caller. And I'll not be picking up any calls which look scammy from now on.

Was the phonecall about taking the girl to a movie relevant? It feels like this call somehow exposed the verification code inside the 1st text.

- **What tactics may have granted the fraudsters access to my account?**
- **Are there additional measures I should take to secure my account? (Is it worth considering changing my phone number?)**

Comment: sim-swap, maybe?:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_swap_scam  (The call could have been to tie you up while they used the code...)

Comment: Is it true that sim-swap would cause my phone to lose connectivity? If so, I don't think it can be the technique since I had connectivity throughout the whole incident. My personal phone was the one which received the one-time verification code...

Comment: I think that's true... do any of your SMS' get forwarded to another service like google voice?

Comment: No, no such thing should occur for any SMS I send!

Comment: The "This is your CIBC verification code" may have been a man-in-the-middle type phish... did you enter the code?

Comment: No, once I noticed I had that text I only checked to see if I could login, and when I couldn't I immediately called the bank

Comment: did you by chance use the link in the "This is your CIBC verification code" message to get to the bank site to login? (or call the # given?)

Comment: more to your question, the phone call could have been simply to check to see if you were available and at your phone to receive a phish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116338/discussion-between-gershom-and-pcalkins).